# Order_by in django sphinx

Tags: django, django-sphinx

I have implemented django-sphinx search in my website.
I need result set **"order by end_time"** but i got results **oder by first "id" and then "end_time"**.

**My conf is:**

```
source main_event : main_civilengagement
{    
    sql_query           = \
        SELECT mc.id as id, mc.name as name, tt.name as ttname, mp.text as mptext, \
        mc.description as description, mc.meta_search as meta_search, \
        mc.start_time as start_time, mc.end_time as end_time \
        FROM main_event mc LEFT JOIN \
            (tagging_taggeditem tti JOIN tagging_tag tt on tti.tag_id=tt.id) \
             on mc.id=tti.object_id and \
                tti.content_type_id=(select id from \
                                     django_content_type where name='event' \
                                     and app_label='main') \
             LEFT JOIN main_post mp on mc.id=mp.object_id \
                                    and mp.content_type_id= \
                                    (select id from \
                                     django_content_type where name='event' \
                                     and app_label='main') 
    # DateField's and DateTimeField's
    sql_attr_timestamp   = start_time
    sql_attr_timestamp   = end_time
}

index main_event : main_civilengagement
{
    source          = main_event
    path            = ../../../sphinx/data/main_event_damco
}
```

**And my view**

```
model_results = model.search.query(keyword,stype).order_by('-end_time')
```

Can anyone help me in sorting out this problem.............

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your config so it has UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) as end_time, reindexing, restarting searchd, and testing after that.